# MLLIb: Saving and loading a model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using `LinearRegressionWithSGD` and then I save the model weights and intercept.

File that contains weights has this format:

```
1.20455
0.1356
0.000456
```

Intercept is 0 since I am using train not setting the intercept so it can be ignored for the moment. I would now like to initialize a new model object and using these saved weights from the above file. We are using CDH 5.1

Something along these lines:

```
// Here is the code the load data and train the model on it.
val weights = sc.textFile("linear-weights");
val model = new LinearRegressionWithSGD(weights);
```

then use is as:

```
// Here is where I want to use the trained model to predict on new data.
val valuesAndPreds = testData.map { point =>
  // Predicting on new data.
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}
```

Any pointers to how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are duplicating the training portion of the LinearRegressionWithSGD - which takes a LibSVM file as input.

- Are you certain that you want to provide your own weights - instead of allowing the library to do its job in the training phase?
- if so, then you can create your own LinearRegressionWithSGD and override the createModel

Here would be your steps given you already have calculated your desired weights / performed the training your own way:

```
 // Stick in your weights below ..
var model = algorithm.createModel(weights, 0.0)

// Now you can run the last steps of the 'normal' process
val prediction = model.predict(test.map(_.features))
val predictionAndLabel = prediction.zip(test.map(_.label))
```

BTW for reference here is the more 'standard' approach that includes the training steps:

```
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, inputFile).cache()

val splits = examples.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1).cache()

val updater = params.regType match {
  case NONE => new SimpleUpdater()
  case L1 => new L1Updater()
  case L2 => new SquaredL2Updater()
}

val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()

val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
algorithm.optimizer
  .setNumIterations(params.numIterations)
  .setStepSize(params.stepSize)
  .setUpdater(updater)
  .setRegParam(params.regParam)

val model = algorithm.run(training)

val prediction = model.predict(test.map(_.features))
val predictionAndLabel = prediction.zip(test.map(_.label))
```